# if statement not working and stopping the whole function from working

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Hi can't get my "if" statement to work. When I write my if the whole function stops working. Without the if, everything works fine.

I tried everything, at least everything I could come up with, which means the use of parseInt, if/else, I read the code again and again, I changed parenthesis, I researched on google. Still nothing. I need a little help!

```js
function myF() {
        
    var num1 = document.getElementById("a").value; 
    var num2 = document.getElementById("b").value;
    var num3 = document.getElementById("c").value;
    var num4 = document.getElementById("d").value;
    var num5 = document.getElementById("e").value;
    var num6 = document.getElementById("f").value;
    var num7 = document.getElementById("g").value;
    var num8 = document.getElementById("h").value;
    var num9 = document.getElementById("i").value;
        
    if (isNaN(num1) || num1 = "") {
        num1 === 0;
    }
        
    var total = parseFloat(num1)+ parseFloat(num2)+parseFloat(num3)+parseFloat(num4)+parseFloat(num5)+parseFloat(num6)+parseFloat(num7)+parseFloat(num8)+parseFloat(num9);
   
     
    var floating2 = document.getElementById("result").value = total.toFixed(2);   
   
    }
```

```css
body { 
     background: url(img/Construction-Wallpaper-8.jpg) repeat-y center center;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

form {
    width: 530px;
    align-content: center;
    margin:45px auto 5px;
    border: solid 1px darkslategrey;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 5px;
    display: block;
}


input {
    float: right;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    top: -4;
}

label {
    padding: 8px 10px;
    font-family: Montauk, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: black;  
    display: block;
}

input#result {
    position: relative;
    right: 10px;
    top: 6px;
}

button#Total {
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
    top: 2px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, darkslategrey, white);
    font-family: Montauk, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 29px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px;
    border: solid 1px black;
}

button#total:active {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    right: 1px;
}

button#total:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

p#title {
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px;
    font-family: Montauk, arial, sans-serif; color: #333;
    font-weight: bolder
}

img#Logo {
    width: 70px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top:15px;
    right: 9px;
}

p#Logo {
    font-family: "Montauk", arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top:-2px;
    right: 105px;
}

label::after {
    float: right;
    content: "$";
    font-size: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    right: 3px;
    bottom: 5px;
}

#total::before {
    content: "$";
    font-size: 25px;
    position: relative;
    left:290px;
    font-family: Montauk, arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bolder;    
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Payment Schedule</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="zzz.css" type="text/css">
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css" type="text/css">
                
    </head>
    
    <body id="body">
        
        <p id="title">&#8226; Payment Schedule &#8226;</p>
        
        <div id="companyName">            
            <p id="Logo">Christopher
            Crawford
            Const.</p>            
        <img src="img/Logo_Crawford1ps.png" id="Logo">            
        </div>        
        
        <form id="sumNumbers">
            
            
            <label >I.Downpayment 5/14 <input id="a" type="text"></label>
        
            <label >II.Progress payment end of week2, @15% <input id="b" type="text"> </label>
        
            <label >III.Progress payment end of week4, @15%  <input id="c" type="text"></label>
        
            <label >IV.Progress payment end of week6, @15% <input id="d" type="text"></label>
            
            <label >V.Progress payment end of week8, @15% <input id="e" type="text"></label>
            
            <label >VI.Progress payment end of week10, @15%  <input id="f" type="text"></label>
            
            <label >VII.Progress payment end of week11, @7.5%  <input id="g" type="text"></label>
            
            <label >VIII.Progress payment end of week12, @7.5% <input id="h" type="text"></label>
            
            <label >IX.Final Payment @10% <input id="i" type="text"></label>        
        
            <button id="total" onclick="myF();" type="button">Total</button>
            <input type="text" id="result">
        </form>
</body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: `num1 = ""` assigns `num1` the value `""` - perhaps you meant to test for equality rather than assign to a value?

Comment: Did you look up what `=` does? (It is not comparison)

Comment: Additionally, `num1 === 0;` is not a very useful expression-statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `if` statement, you should use `===` to test for equality.  `=` is the assignment operator, which you should in the line below, i.e. `num1 = 0;`.

Comment: Don't bother answering trivial typo questions like this. It makes it harder to delete the question after it's closed.

Comment: But stll it works only for the first input. Infact when I leave the second or the third or the other inputs empty, the result I get is NaN.

Comment: No problemo - glad you learned!  What's happening there is that you're trying to `parseFloat()` something that's not a number (something empty,) which returns "NaN".  You tested num1, but none of the numbers to make sure of this.  What I would do is write a `for` loop to run that if statement for every `numx`.  Does that make sense?